# Opencart 1.5x - add '.html' at the end of product url

Tags: php, opencart

How can I add at the end of product url the extension '.html'.
-My current product link:
www.mysite.com/productlink
-I want to be:
www.mysite.com/productlink.html

I edited catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php, the product url now has .html but when I click a link it says 404 not found. What do I need to do ?

```
if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id') || ($data['route'] == 'news/article' && $key == 'news_id')) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) .   "'");

if ($query->num_rows) {
    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'] . '.html';                     
    unset($data[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using .htaccess
try this: I haven't tested this so it may need some tweaking.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.html [R=301,L,NE]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It's working but this method will put on every link .html.I need this only in product pages. The reason is I will remake a website and the SEO person wants all links to be the same as old site and only in products page is the '.html' at the end.

Comment: and if you replace `index.php?_route_=$1` with this: `index.php?route=product/$1`